# Internet Explorer is missing the address bar

Tags: internet-explorer, toolbar

My cat walks across the keyboard of my laptop (it is nice and warm).

Unfortunately, I have lost the address bar in Internet Explorer.

How do I get it back?

Comment: Under View > Toolbars, there is no entry for Address Bar

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Support had the answer, unsurprisingly.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/962963

1. Close all open Internet Explorer and Windows Explorer windows.
2. Click Start, and then click Run.
3. In the Open box, type regedit, and then click OK.
4. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
     HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar
5. Use one or both of the following steps, as appropriate for your situation:
         * For Windows Explorer: In the details pane, locate the Explorer subkey, and then open it. In the details pane, locate the ITBarLayout value. Right-click this value, and then click Delete.
         * For Internet Explorer: In the details pane, locate the WebBrowser subkey, and then open it. In the details pane, locate the ITBarLayout value. Right-click this value, and then click Delete.
6. On the File menu, click Exit to exit Registry Editor.
7. Restart Internet Explorer

Comment: When I started reading I thought you were going to say that MS Support had instructions for what to do when your cat walks across your keyboard ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think there were a key shortcut `CTRL+M`. Not very sure about it.

And it is not good to let your cat near your computers. Their hair tends to clog the cooling fans and it is more likely that an overheat will occure.

Comment: CTRL+M does not work unfortunately.